# Golang container/list create an adjacency list

Tags: list, go

I was trying to build an adjacency list with golang.

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

type SocialGraph struct {
    // define the size
    V int
    // define the type of array of int list, row is the list order, column is the list of neighbors
    // whether to create array from make or just define?
    Arr map[int]*list.List
}

func AddEdge(g SocialGraph, i, j int, undir bool) {
    /*
        param g: instance of SocialGraph
        param i: edge start
        param j: edge end
        param undir: whether directed
    */

    g.Arr[i].PushBack(j)
    if undir {
        g.Arr[j].PushBack(i)
    }
    fmt.Println(g)
}

func PrintEdgeList(g SocialGraph) {
    for i := 0; i <= g.V; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("the neighbor of %d includes %v \n", i, g.Arr[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    graph := SocialGraph{V: 6, Arr: make(map[int]*list.List, 7)}
    fmt.Println(graph)
    AddEdge(graph, 1, 3, true)
    AddEdge(graph, 2, 3, true)
    AddEdge(graph, 2, 4, true)
    AddEdge(graph, 1, 5, true)
    AddEdge(graph, 1, 6, true)

    PrintEdgeList(graph)
}
```

I was using list.List to define the list of neighbors, but I always got error with:

```
container/list.(*List).lazyInit(...)
        E:/Go/src/container/list/list.go:86
container/list.(*List).PushBack(...)
        E:/Go/src/container/list/list.go:151
main.AddEdge({0xc00002e000?, 0xc00007feb0?}, 0x9b5cca?, 0xc000062000?, 0x1)
```

I am not sure whether I should define the value in map with map[int][]list.List or map[int]*list.List

Answer (score 1):

This SocialGraph's Arr Not initialized, I think you shoud initialized Arr, just like this, or other initialized method

```golang
func AddEdge(g SocialGraph, i, j int, undir bool) {
    /*
        param g: instance of SocialGraph
        param i: edge start
        param j: edge end
        param undir: whether directed
    */
    if g.Arr[i] == nil {
        g.Arr[i] = list.New()
    }
    g.Arr[i].PushBack(j)
    if undir {
        if g.Arr[j] == nil {
            g.Arr[j] = list.New()
        }
        g.Arr[j].PushBack(i)
    }
    fmt.Println(g)
}
```